# property and setter attributes in python

Tags: python, oop

I am new in python and in OOP term and I am kind of confused about private and public attributes specifically with property and setter decorator and i wnat to know which is the best way to write the attributes in python when using property and setter, is it using private or public attributes in our `__init__` method and why?

1. public attributes

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
```

then implement property and setter for each attribute.

or using private attributes in our constructor

2. Private attributes

```
class Emp():
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.__id = id
        self.__name = name
```

then implement property and setter for each attribute.

and thanks in advance for any helps.

Comment: If you're implementing a public getter/setter for each attribute that just returns/sets the underlying private attribute without any other side effects or computation, just use a public attribute.  No point adding needless complication.  If you want public properties that are gettable but not settable, use `@dataclass(frozen=True)`.  Note that Python doesn't really have the concept of a "private" attribute except by convention; prefixing an attribute with a single underscore is understood by most people to mean "private".  Two underscores adds "name mangling"; if you don't know why, don't.